# Can we define a new multiplication on $\Bbb R$ ( addition and identity element remain the same) while its properties of being a field persist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, real-numbers

1. If the identity element of $\Bbb R$ were permitted to be redefined, then it could be redefined as any nonzero number while keeping $\Bbb R$ a field;
2. By induction, we can prove that only the product between irrational numbers of the new multiplication could be different from that of the common multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\Bbb R$ is a $\Bbb Q$-vector space.
If $f$ is any non-identity automorphism of this vector space (perhaps with the additional demand that $f(1)=1$), defining $x*y:=f^{-1}(f(x)\cdot f(y))$ does what you desire.

Comment: Does there exist more trivial method of constructing such automorphism on R, the Q-vector space? I used transfinite induction to pair irrationals.

Comment: @JihaiZhu I am cerrtain that a sufficiently strong flavour of the Axiom of Choice is needed. Picking a Hamel basis and mapping $v\mapsto -v$ for one base element and $v\mapsto v$ for all others looks like quickly done, but of course is not (and cannot be) explicit